# QuickBooks on Amazon Workspaces?

Tags: amazon-web-services, quickbooks

I'm trying to get QuickBooks Desktop 2021 working on multiple instances of Amazon Workspaces. My end goal is for each Windows 10 Workspace to access our QuickBooks company file via a mapped drive from an Amazon EC2 instance running Windows Server 2019. I can log in to the company file if I run QuickBooks on the server, but when I log in to it on a Workspace, QuickBooks crashes with no error code. The same happens even if I copy the company file to a local drive on the Workspace, in an attempt to remove the networking part of the equation.

I've spent many hours on the phone with Intuit support while sharing my screen, and we've tried uninstalling and reinstalling QB, as well as running the QB File Doctor, and various repair programs in QB Tool Hub. It appears that there's no problem with the company file because it opens fine on both the EC2 server and the Windows Server 2012 we currently use in our office. It also appears that there's no problem with the QB installation on the Workspace because it's identical to what's running on the EC2 server and our Windows 10 client PCs in our office.

One very odd thing I've discovered though... If I open a test company file that I created on the Workspace, it opens fine. If I then go to the File menu (while the test file is still open) and select "Open or Restore Company", and then open our company file, it opens fine every time. But if I close QB and try to open our company file again, QB crashes every time. It also crashes if I open the test file, then close it without exiting QB, and then try to open our company file. The only combination that works is if I open the test file and then do an automatic close/reopen to switch from the test file to our company file.

Has anyone actually gotten QB to work in a multi-user (or even single-user) environment on AWS Workspaces? How did you do it?

Thanks,
Russell

Comment: Did QB support state that this is a supported scenario? If they didn't specifically say that then I would specifically ask them. Does Amazon have a list of supported applications for Workspaces?

Comment: @joeqwerty - The Intuit agents I've spoken to had no idea what AWS was, much less Workspaces. I haven't found a list of apps officially supported by Workspaces but I've seen random posts on the web implying that it should be possible - I'm just hoping someone can tell me for sure, and maybe how.